# ORACLE SQL // IF ELSE?

Tags: oracle

I got a small problem in my SQL code :

```
LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT *
              FROM pilotage_usines_valeurs
             WHERE c_indicateur IS NOT NULL) v
              ON     v.id_usine = d.id_usine
                 AND v.annee = 2015
                 AND V.MOIS = D.MOIS
                 AND V.C_INDICATEUR = pi1.c_indicateur
```

Sometime `pi1.c_indicateur is null`. How can i test it and write the line `if pi1.c_indicateur is not null` don't write it `if pi1.c_indicateur is null` ?

Comment: I know NVL but how to use it here ? In general i use it on a field like
`NVL(pi1.c_indicateur,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intentions correctly I suggest you add the NOT NULL condition to the ON clause:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
             FROM PILOTAGE_USINES_VALEURS
             WHERE C_INDICATEUR IS NOT NULL) v
  ON v.ID_USINE = d.ID_USINE
     AND v.ANNEE = 2015
     AND v.MOIS = D.MOIS
     AND v.C_INDICATEUR = pi1.C_INDICATEUR
     AND pi1.C_INDICATEUR IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I had tought of that but my problem wasn't there, it was a bit under :
`WHERE    d.id_simu = '1168' AND V.valeur IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id_simu, id_element`

Added the line : 
`OR (pi1.c_indicateur IS NULL AND d.id_simu = '1168'))`
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

NVL is used to substitute null value by something else. Syntax is similar to

```
NVL (FIELD_TO_BE_TESTED_FOR_NULL, VALUE_IF_NULL);
```

**Option 1:**
 Replace pi1.c_indicateur when null with some value so that V.C_INDICATEUR will never be equal to that value.

```
AND V.C_INDICATEUR = NVL(pi1.c_indicateur,'IMPOSSIBLE VALUE FOR V.C_INDICATEUR ');
```

**Option 2:**
  Replace V.C_INDICATEUR with some value if null and replace pi1.c_indicateur with some other value, so that both will never match if NULL.

```
AND (V.C_INDICATEUR,'ABC') = NVL(pi1.c_indicateur,'DEF');
```